# Por qué parpadean las formas al ejecutar Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Tags: excel, vba

Para evitar molestos efectos visuales mientras se ejecuta código, es ampliamente utilizado iniciar la ejecución con `Aplication.ScreenUpdating = False` y terminarla con `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`.

Sin embargo esto provoca un parpadeo molesto de las formas (desaparecen y vuelven a aparecer) tras el screen updating final. Curiosamente no ocurre con todas las formas, sólo con algunas, por ejemplo las formas que he creado con texto dentro no parpadean, pero las imágenes que he insertado desde archivos sí.

Alguien sabría decirme a qué se debe esto y cómo puedo evitarlo.

Gracias.
Saludos.

Comment: Haz el libro invisible. En cualquier caso, creo que esta pregunta queda fuera del objetivo de SO en español, que es pura programación. Quizás en Superuser puedan ayudarte.

Comment: Esei, agradezco tu consejo. No entiendo cómo puede mejorar la cosa hacer el libro invisible (y volver a hacerlo visible, supongo), pero lo probaré. En cuanto al otro asunto, creo que en esta web tenéis demasiadas normas incomprensibles, aplicadas demasiadas veces de forma caprichosa. Creo que mi consulta SÍ es sobre programación, y aunque fuera genérica sobre Excel no entiendo por qué no debería hacerla en este sitio, una de cuyas etiquetas creo es [Excel]. Gracias. Un saludo.